# 500 internal server error when submit data from AJAX in live server in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, server

I am getting error when submit data from ajax on live server which website is made in asp.net with c#.

The error is "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Here is my code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#submit_mail", function (e) {
            if (validateform() == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "contact.aspx/SendMail",

                    data: JSON.stringify({ name: $('#txt_name').val(), email: $('#txt_emailID').val(), subject: $('#txt_subject').val(), message: $('#txt_content').val() }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Email Send Successfully, we will contact you successfully...!!!");
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("There is some problem in server to contact with us....Please contact with contact number...!!!");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, this is code. This code is working perfectly in local server. While in live server this code not working.

When I debug this ajax from developer tools it shows that it calls the ajax line i.e. 
`$.ajax({` and end it `)};` 
in between the debug is not going and so from thats why in webserver method which is server side code it going null data and showing 500 internal server error.

Here is server side code

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(10000);
        // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
        var fromAddress = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = email.Trim();
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string sub = subject.Trim();
        string body = "From: " + name.Trim() + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + email.Trim() + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + subject.Trim() + "\n";
        body += "Message: \n" + message.Trim() + "\n";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, sub, body);
    }
```

So, in short my question is that why in AJAX method debug is not taking the url, data and other content of AJAX. Because for my thinking this error is coming when data is taking the url, data and other content from AJAX.

Comment: show me c# code.

Comment: I have update the data please review it. But for my thinking there is ajax problem because it ajax it is not content url, data and other content and from that the webserver method is null. And hence getting this error.

Comment: seems url problem url ur puting is not able to find method u r calling can you paste ur console error here?

Answer (score 0):

```js
////Send Email on button click
function SendEmail(url) {

    obj = {};
    obj.Name = $("#txtName").val();
    obj.Email = $("#txtEmail").val();
    obj.MobileNo = $("#txtMobileNo").val();

    obj.Subject = ($("#txtSubject").val() != '') ? $("#txtSubject").val() : '';
    obj.Message = ($("#txtMessage").val() != '') ? $("#txtMessage").val() : '';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        $.each(response.d, function () {

            var Msg;
            var Result;
            Msg = this['Text'];
            Result = this['Value'];

            if (Result > 0) {
                Clear();
                $("#AlertClass").attr("style", "display: block")
                $('#AlertClass').addClass('alert alert-success text-center');
                $('#lblResult').append('<span><img src="assets/images/Serve.png" style=" height: 40px;" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;' + Msg + '</span>');

            } else {
                $("#AlertClass").attr("style", "display: block")
                $('#AlertClass').addClass('alert alert-danger text-center');
                $('#lblResult').append('<span>"' + Msg + '"</span>');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<ListItem> SendEmail(string Name, string Email, string MobileNo, string Subject, string Message)
        {
          
            int Return = 0;
            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ReturnMessage.Add(new ListItem
                {
                    Value = "0",
                    Text = "There is an error try again after some time!"
                });
            }

            return ReturnMessage;
        }
```

try this one.

Comment: by trying your code in local server only it shows the 500 (Internal Server Error)